# Angular Service - Why is the primitive value not updated?

Tags: angular, angular-services, injectable

I'm figuring out how Angular Services work, but I don't understand why the heroCounter (number) doesn't update correctly while the hero array does. For instance, as I add a new dummy hero I expect the heroCounter to increment.

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

**hero.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../model/hero.model';
import { HEROES } from '../constants/hero.constant';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HeroService {
  heroes!: Hero[];
  heroesCounter!:number;

  constructor() {
    this.heroes = HEROES;
    this.heroesCounter = this.heroes.length;
  }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(this.heroes);
  }

  getHeroesCounter(): Observable<number> {
    return of(this.heroesCounter);
  }

  mockAddHero(name: string): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.heroes.push(new Hero(name));
      this.heroesCounter = this.heroes.length;
      console.log(this.heroesCounter);
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from '../services/hero.service';
import { Hero } from '../model/hero.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes!: Hero[];
  heroesCounter!: number;
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe((heroes) => (this.heroes = heroes));
  }

  getHeroesCounter(): void {
 
    this.heroService
      .getHeroesCounter()
      .subscribe((counter) => {this.heroesCounter = counter});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
    this.getHeroesCounter();
  }

  addHero(): void {
    this.heroService.mockedAddHero('new hero');
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="addHero()" >Add Dummy Hero</button>
  <ul> 
    <!-- This works -->
    @for(hero of heroes; track $index){
      <li>{{hero.name}}</li>
    }
  </ul>
  <!-- This does not work -->
  <p> Total of heroes: {{this.heroesCounter}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `getHeroesCounter` method of the `HeroService` return `of(this.heroesCounter)`, and `of` function will emit a variable amount of values in a sequence and then emit a complete notification.

As a result, when you add a new hero to the list, the subscribe method will not be triggered, even though you trigger the change detection yourself with the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` or `setTimeout`, ...

The `heroService.getHeroes()` also returns `of(heroes)`, but the heroes list is an array - a reference type.

[More information about of can be found at](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)

[Here is a demo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nmyj4?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

have a `getHeroesCounter complete!` message in the Console

To resolve your issue, you should use the `Subject` in HeroService to store the hero list.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can gather from your code, this would be because angular change detection works with memory references (among other things) : updating a memory reference triggers the change detection.

This is what happens with your array : your set a new value into its memory reference.

But it does not work like this for primitive values (strings, numbers, booleans).

If you wish to make it work, you should trigger the change detection yourself with the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

But more importantly, I would suggest you first learn more about the observables and how they work, particularly with the `async` pipe : your code is very prone to issues like this, and using the observables correctly would prevent most of them from happening.

In other terms : this is a edge case you created by mistake, don't loose too much time over it and keep learning !

Comment: -1 for leaving the incorrect impression that change detection "does not work for primitive types" and incorrectly claiming that triggering change detection manually will resolve the issue.

Comment: Agreed, I was paraphrasing to make a simpler message. But triggering by hand will indeed work.